# Sequelize/tedious create/update records with long string error: read ECONNRESET

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js, tedious

I am trying to use sequelize/tedious to access Azure SQL database with CRUD operations. I have a long string (Signature) in one of the tables.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Owner](
    [OwnerId] [int] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Signature] [varchar](max) NULL
)
```

Here is my sequelize model:

```
/* owner.js */
export default function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Owner = sequelize.define(
    'Owner',
    {
      ownerId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'OwnerId',
      },
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true,
        },
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'Name',
      },
      signature: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(50000),
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true,
        },
        allowNull: true,
        field: 'Signature',
      },
    },
    {
      schema: 'dbo',
      timestamps: false,
      freezeTableName: true,
    }
  );

  return Owner;
}
```

And here is code to read and create records:

```
/* index.js */
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

var db = {};

var sequelize = new Sequelize('mydb', 'developer', 'mypassword', {
  host: 'mydevserver.database.windows.net',
  dialect: 'mssql',
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  },
  dialectOptions: {
    options: {
      encrypt: true
    }
  }
});


db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

var model = sequelize['import']('./owner.js');
db[model.name] = model;

/* Find a record with long signature (8000 chars) is fine. */
db.Owner.findByPk(6)
.then(o => {
  console.log(`Found owner ${o.name}, with signature ${o.signature}.`);
})

// let s = '0123456789'.repeat(100); /* This is ok. Record created. */
let s = '0123456789'.repeat(500); /* This gives error 'read ECONNRESET' */

db.Owner.create({  
  name: 'Rick',
  signature: `${s}`
})
.then(newOwner => {
  console.log(`New owner ${newOwner.name}, with id ${newOwner.ownerId} has been created.`);
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error.message);
});
```

I am using

```
  "sequelize": "^5.10.1",
  "tedious": "^6.2.0"
```

I know there will be a limit for the string you can input, but a 5000-char string is not that long.

Any idea what's wrong? Here is the stack trace of the error

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: read ECONNRESET
    at Query.formatError (C:\work\GitRepos\sequelize-test\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\query.js:309:12)
    at Request.userCallback (C:\work\GitRepos\sequelize-test\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\query.js:69:23)
    at Request.callback (C:\work\GitRepos\sequelize-test\node_modules\tedious\lib\request.js:37:27)
    at Connection.socketError (C:\work\GitRepos\sequelize-test\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:2157:20)
    at Connection.dispatchEvent (C:\work\GitRepos\sequelize-test\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1172:36)
    at Connection.socketError (C:\work\GitRepos\sequelize-test\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1190:10)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\work\GitRepos\sequelize-test\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1032:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:205:15)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:471:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:9)
```

UPDATE:

If I increase the packet size for the connection,

```
dialectOptions: {
    options: {
      encrypt: true,
      packetSize: 32768
    }
  }
```

then the problem was solved. Even if I increase the length of string to a much larger number, e.g.

```
let s = '0123456789'.repeat(500000);
```

it still works. This doesn't make sense to me. At server side, why the packets were not re-assembled when the packet size is 4096 (default), but at a larger packet size, the packets were re-assembled. Also at the client side, the packets are always re-assembled no matter what the packet size is.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this was a [bug](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/issues/923) in Tedious that was fixed in 6.2.1. I came across it when I switched my NodeJS apps in Azure to use NodeJS 12.

The workaround noted above about increasing the packet size does work and that's what I implemented, because I'm using Sequelize 4 and I'm not sure if the current versions of Tedious are compatible (I seem to remember reading somewhere on the web that you need a certain version to keep Sequelize 4 happy).